# unable to change body background color using javascript callback

Tags: javascript, css

I am learning to program in Javascript. I have created a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/vvMRX/1/

```
function turnRed(node,f){
  setTimeout(f,2000,[node]);
}

(function pageLoaded(){
  turnRed(document.body,function(node){
    alert(node);node.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
  });
})();
```

I am trying to use a `setTimeout` call on a function to change the body background color. I pass `document.body` as a node. In the callback, I change the `node.style.backgroundColor` but it does not work. Interestingly enough, using `document.body.style.backgroundColor` directly works. If I put an `alert(node)`, it correctly identifies it as html `bodyelement`.

What am I missing here?

Appreciate responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the following error that's being thrown in your JS:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined`

The reason for this is because in your `setTimeout`, you're passing `node` in an array. However, in your callback, you're accessing the node directly. Two ways of addressing this are:

**Update your callback to access the `node` within the `array`.**

```
(function pageLoaded(){
    turnRed( document.body, function(node){ 
        alert(node);

        // Updated code below
        node[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    });
})();
```

**The other way would be to update your setTimeout and pass node directly.**

```
function turnRed(node,f){
    setTimeout(f,2000,node);
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvMRX/3/

You mentioned that using `document.body.style.backgroundColor` worked - which makes sense - since `document.body` will point to the `element` that contains the content. For most pages, this is almost always the `<body>` element. However, for `frameset` documents, this would return the outer frame. ([w3.org reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-56360201))

Finally, regarding the `alert` - what's up with that, right? You call `alert(node)`, and it displays `[object HTMLBodyElement]`, which means you were passing the correct `element`, right? (***At least, that's what I would think too!***)

What's actually happening is that `alert` is alerting the value of your array.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating that: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lf3J/

You should see three alerts.

In the first `alert`, I've updated the original alert to call `node.constructor`. `Object.prototype.constructor` will return a reference to the object that created the instance ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)).

In this case, we'll see

`function Array() { [native code] }`

This hopefully will re-enforce the idea that you're passing an `array`.

The second `alert` is actually calling `alert(document.body.constructor)`, which is what we EXPECTED to see originally. In this case, we see:

`function HTMLBodyElement() { [native code] }`

Finally, a third `alert` shows the values `1,2,3,4,5`, which is just an alert of a simple array with those values (again, re-enforcing the idea that alerts will alert the value of an array - which is why you thought the alert was correct).

Hopefully this helps as you continuing learning JavaScript!

Comment: Eh, thanks for such detailed info ! Actually, I did not realize that I was passing an array. The first link from Google results when I searched setTimeout was https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout Look at the documentation. It uses [] ! That led me to believe that I need to use [] (just like you would do in apply method). I thought [] was syntactic sugar. Now that I realize that it was an array, rest of it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `turnRed` you are passing node in an array. Try this:

```
function turnRed(node,f){
    setTimeout(f,2000,node);
}
```

I tried this in the fiddle it works.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i guess that you should use document.bgColor property directly

You can obtain more information and code samples here:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/backgrou.htm

http://www.webcodingtech.com/javascript/change-background-color.php